# Upgrading from Datastax java driver for apache cassandra 2.1.9 to DSE java driver 1.2.4

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver

I am upgrading from DataStax Java driver for apache cassandra 2.1.9 to DSE java driver 1.2.4. After upgrade i see issue on server. The thread count keep increasing from netty class `io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory`. With current driver our application is running in production successfully. We see just one thread from same class.

After 20 mins of application starting, write and read transactions start to fail with the following exception:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: 
All host(s) tried for query failed (no host was tried)
```

Comment: What is your C* version?

Comment: We are using DSE 4.8